# DFS on undirected graph complexity

Tags: graph, time-complexity, depth-first-search

Let's say I have an undirected graph with V nodes and E edges.If I represent the graph with adjacency lists,if I have a representation of an edge between x and y,I must also have a representation of the edge between y and x in the adjacency list.

I know that DFS for directed graphs has V+E complexity.For undirected graphs doesn't it have v+2*e complexity ,because you visit each edge 2 times ?Sorry if it's a noobish question..I really want to understand this think.Thank you,

Comment: See answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468621/why-is-the-time-complexity-of-both-dfs-and-bfs-o-v-e

Comment: If the graph is acyclic then the cost is Theta(|V|). It can be otherwise stated that detecting a cycle in undirected graph takes O(|V|) time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity is normally expressed O(|V| + |E|) and this isn't affected by the factor of 2.

But the factor of 2 is actually there.  One undirected edge behaves just line 2 directed edges.  E.g. the algorithm (for a connected undirected graph) is

```
visit(v) {
  mark(v)
  for each unmarked w adjacent to v, visit(w)
}
```

The for loop will consider each edge incident to each vertex once.  Since each undirected edge is incident to 2 vertices, it will clearly be considered twice!

Note the undirected DFS doesn't have to worry about restarting from all the sources.  You can pick any vertex.