# Time complexity of Depth First Search with back edges

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, traversal

I'm new to DFS and just learned that the time complexity of DFS will be O(V+E) if using an adjacency list. I was wondering what the time complexity of DFS would be if back edges were included, as back edges require the search to backtrack to previously discovered nodes.

I tried searching this up online but I can't seem to find a good answer for this.

Comment: Which sources did you find which said it is only O(V+E) when there are no back-edges?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468621/why-is-the-time-complexity-of-both-dfs-and-bfs-o-v-e

i assumed that it applies to DFS in general, but I was wondering what the time complexity would be if back edges were included

Comment: The second answer to that question explicitly mentions back-edges: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468703/12299000 Back-edges are expected as a normal part of the DFS algorithm, any discussion of its complexity should involve the case where there are back-edges.