# Time Complexity of DFS and BFS

Tags: time-complexity, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, pseudocode

I'm new to the search strategies. Does anyone know how to analyze the time complexity of the figure below?

[image: Algorithm for DFS and BFS]

Comment: I'd start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Analysis) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Complexity)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the time complexity of both DFS and BFS O( V + E )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468621/why-is-the-time-complexity-of-both-dfs-and-bfs-o-v-e)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to analyse time complexity for such problems is to check how many times a vertex and edge is accessed. Since in both BFS and DFS a single node is only visited once we can say it would be O(V + E) where v is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges.